# SAPUI5 - Accessing Sub Account ID from within controller

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I'm accessing a URI from my controller which at the moment is hardcoded to my current SAP Cloud Platform Sub-Account.

window.open("https://rsaactionplan-(subaccount).dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/index.html#/actionplan/" + oBindingContext.JobId, "_system");

Rather than hard-code it, how can I access the ***current*** sub-account ID so I can dynamically setup the sub-account in the SAPUI5 controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to account related details using Tenant Context APIs.

Please check here for details https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/a8f2255658ba4cbfb3ec3ab0f928f360.html?q=TenantContext

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

My solution for both hybrid + web app.

following any oData Read......

```
    var uriStr; 

    if (typeof sap.hybrid !== 'undefined') {
        uriStr = oUserData.__metadata.uri;
    }
    else{
        uriStr = window.location.href;
    }

    var split1 = uriStr.split("-");  // split by - 
    var secondSubString = split1[1]; // all characters AFTER the first -
    var split2 = secondSubString.split(".");  // split by . 
    self.subAccount = split2[0];  // all characters BEFORE the first .
```

Then use self.subAccount into the calling URI.